# Markdown fails to render bullets and paragraphs nested inside collapsed elements, when published on Github Pages

Tags: github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

So, I created this page with public information.

It all renders beautifully when I access it through https://github.com/portotype/decodeportugal.com/blob/main/README.md

Example: open "Power of representation", and there's 4 paragraphs and 2 bullets.

But when GitHub puts it out as a page in https://decodeportugal.com, then the text is all in-line, no paragraphs and no bullets.

Is is some detail in markdown?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the answer posted here: https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/155

All I needed to do was to add a "markdown" tag inside details:

Power of Representation.